# One function for every Combobox in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple sources for one information, so I thought it would be the best to add an ComboBox next to it. With it the user shall choose the source for the information. Im using MS Access with VBA.

It has to look like this (the last column is the combobox):

```
-------------------------------------------
Name: | North Rhine-Westfalia | Source1 [v]
-------------------------------------------
```

So now you can click on the arrow in the ComboBox and choose another source; then a SQL query will be executed. It should looke like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
Name: | Nordrhein-Westfalen   | Source2 [v]
-------------------------------------------
```

The problem is, that I have multiple ComboBoxes for each and every information (+50) and that I dont want to write an code for every single one. How could I implement one elegant function for every ComboBox?

I really hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You aren't clear if you are trying to create the comboboxes or just process them.  If you already have them created, then what you're doing sounds like a control array, which is available in VB, but I don't believe is available in Access.  This link shows a workaround by iterating through control names, assuming they are named consistently.  I've been out of Access coding too long to post my own answer, but maybe someone else can do that: 
http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0038.htm

Answer (score 0):

If the operations performed by changing the combo-boxes are consistent, you can write a single subroutine that takes the combo-box value and does something with it. Then that subroutine can be referenced in each combo-box's `AfterUpdate` method.

For example:

```
Private Sub DoComboBoxThing(varComboValue as Variant)
    'Do something here with the combobox value
End Sub
```

This function is then called by the combo box after update:

```
Private Sub Combo_Box_AfterUpdate ()
    DoComboBoxThing Combo_Box.Value
End Sub
```

You can point all of the combo boxes to the same subroutine.

Comment: You can also pass a reference to the combo box, instead of its value. That way the same function can reach back and change the value or formatting of the referenced object.